# How does the browser's javascript garbage collection work?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, garbage-collection

Do I have to destroy instances myself? ...if I don't assign them a variable...will they automatically go away?

```
new ImageUploadView();
```

vs

```
var Iu = ImageUploadView();
```

Comment: Yes, they are garbage-collected. Objects exist as long as there exists at least one reference to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no reference to an object in javascript, the garbage collector will clean it up.

The way the garbage collector works is it looks for javascript objects for which nobody has a reference to.  If nobody has a reference to it, then it can't be used again, so it can be deleted and the memory it occupied reclaimed.  On the other hand, if any javascript entity still has a reference to the object, then it is still "in use" and cannot be deleted.

In your first code example:

```
new ImageUploadView();
```

unless the constructor of the object stores away the `this` pointer into some other variable or object or creates some closure that causes references to the object to be held, then there will be no reference to this new object and it will be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

If you second code example:

```
var Iu = ImageUploadView();
```

as long as the `Iu` variable exists and stays in scope it will contain whatever the `ImageUploadView()` function returns.  Note, the second example, is just executing a function and storing it's value.  It is not necessarily creating anything.  If `ImageUploadView()` just returns `true`, then that's all the `Iu` variable will contain.

Comment: So, as long as the variable exists, it will contain the value it contains. Got it. `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - I added "stays in scope" to better convey what I was trying to say.

Comment: @jfriend - not so.  Execute this in your JavaScript console: `function Obj () { return true; }; var o = new Obj(); o == true;`.  My console displays false.  `new SomeFunction()` returns an `Object`, not the return value of `SomeFunction()`.

Comment: @gilly3 - his second code example does not have a `new` in it.  It's just a function call.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Ah, I missed that.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first method is fine.  Assuming that the instance of `ImageUploadView` is appropriately cleaning up after itself, it will be collected by the garbage collector.

Comment: It's return value will be garbage collected, that is... (not the constructor itself).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Indeed.  I added a couple of clarifying words.

Comment: @gilly3, how do i make sure "ImageUplaodView" is appropriately cleaning up itself?

Comment: @user847495 - If `ImageUploadView` is doing anything outside of its own scope, references to it could stick around.  For example, creating Global variables, adding properties to DOM or Global objects, binding events - particularly if using closures, or otherwise passing around closures.

Answer (score 0):

With large objects, it's not necessarily a good practice to assume that the browsers built in garbage collector will clean up once it's out of scope. You're better off to clear it ourself using "delete". For example:

```
delete MyImageUploadView;
```

Edit: it may be preferable to set the object to null if it isnt being referenced as a property.